# After ajax call data is null in webapi?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am working on webapi here I am getting null data after an ajax call. How could I get the data?

Here my ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var editor = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('editor1');
$('#btndiv').mouseleave(function (event) {
    $('#btndiv1').hide("slow");
        alert(1);
        var data1 = editor.getData();
        $('#btndiv').append(data1);
    // send your ajax request with value

        var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(data1);
        alert('hi');
        alert(data1 + "got data");
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/api/UpdateCkeditor",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataToPost,
            dataType: "json",
            statusCode: {
                200: function (data1) {
                    alert("Updated successfully");
                }
            }
            //success: function (value) {
            //    // do what you want on success.
            //    alert("Updated successfully");

            //}
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

and here my controllers:

```
  public void create(ckeditormodels data1)
    {
        webapiEntities db = new webapiEntities();

        var empObj = db.ckeditorDatas.First(c => c.id == 1);
        empObj.value = data1.value;

        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

here my models:

```
    public class ckeditormodels
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string dataToPost { get; set; }
    public string data1 { get; set; }
}
```

Here I am getting my data null. How to get data form ajax call to my controllers? Any help appreciated - thanks.

Comment: check data set to object and then get response object and check its results

Comment: i had checked in ajax call i have a deat once it moves to controller it is null how how to get the data could u guide me how could i do that

Comment: I don't know the asp.net web api, but firstly your success function has no argument defined: `success(data)`. Secondly is the POST working (you have show a PUT controller action)? Can you see the XHR response in Firebug or similar?

Comment: I wonder how does your request data and `ckeditormodels` looks. By default `getData` returns raw string so what are your data suppose to look like?

Comment: i will update my ckeditormodels actually i am having here data in value and i want return that data to my controllers could u check it plz i wil update

Comment: Can you add your request content (from Fiddler or FireBug) as I believe there is no id it that request, where it is suppose to come from?

Comment: You are making a `POST` request through your jQuery code but your action method corresponds to a `PUT` request.

Comment: yes i had tried as u said but i getting null in my controllers i had updated my question could u check it plz

Comment: here i am getting an error object reference not set to an instance of object cause data is null in controller

Comment: We have a little bit of chaos over here - I hope I get your question correctly.

Comment: let me explain u here iam writing some data in ckeditor k once mouse moves out of ckeditor mouseleave function will fire right

Comment: from here my task stats from here i need to get the data which is having in   here  var data1 = editor.getData(); right

Comment: from data1 to iam calling ajax function to get that data to my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getData()` method of CKEditor is returning raw data from editor (the same that editor would post by itself). You need to wrap that string to better fit your model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('editor1');
    $('#btndiv').mouseleave(function (event) {
            ...
            var rawEditorValue = editor.getData();
            ...
            //If you want more properties here just extend this object
            var dataToPost = JSON.stringify({ value: rawEditorValue });
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the result the `rawEditorValue` data from editor will be bind to `value` property of your model. I also assume here that the request is hitting your action (the URL and method doesn't seem to fit but yoru are saying that the action is hit and only the data is null so I trust you).

Comment: yes its working but i am having one more error its saying like this could u checkit plz the error:Unable to update the EntitySet 'ckeditorData' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.

Comment: it is occuring at place db.SaveChanges();  in controllers  i got the data but it should make the changes thanks for my reply

Comment: thanks @mr.tpeczek but having one error same as above comment could u check it plz

Comment: @Shakil This error usually happens if entity set is mapped from database view, custom database query or if database table doesn't have primary key. It is hard to say what is the exact reason but there is a lot of SO questions related to this subject which you can read --> http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DefiningQuery+and+no+%3CUpdateFunction%3E. If none of those helps you I suggest you ask separate question for the Entity Framework part as this is no longer jQuery or Web API related issue - this part has been asnwered here.

Comment: @ tpeczek thanks friend thanks alot giving reply for my question thanks alot nice coding